# Give a sequence of random variables that converges to a non-constant limit in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Intuitively, I feel like there shouldn't exist such a sequence.

We need $\mathbb{E}((X_n - X)^2) \rightarrow 0$, and if $X_n$ indeed did converge to $X$, we would probably expect $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = \mathbb{E} (X)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

But then, roughly speaking, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\mathbb{E}((X_n - X)^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_n^2 - 2X_n \cdot X + X^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - 2\mathbb{E}(X)^2 + \mathbb{E}(X^2) = 2(\mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2) = 2 \ Var(X)$.

So we need X to be a random variable whose variance goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But the variance of X wouldn't depend on n, so we need Var$(X) = 0$, i.e. a constant random variable.

Where did my intuition go wrong, because the question implies that such a sequence of random variables does exist, and what is an example of such a random variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $X_n =X$ for all $n$. Then $X_n \to X$ in $L^{2}$ (in fact, in every sense!) and $X$ is not  a constant.

Of course, we can take $X$ to be any non-constant random variable instead of a standard normal random variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, here you are saying that $X_n = X$ in the sense that the value of $X_n$ takes on whatever value X is, as opposed to that they are equal in distribution. Because if we took $X_n$ and $X$ to both be normally distributed, but independent of each other, then I find that $X_n$ does not converge to $X$ in $L^2$. (In particular, $\mathbb{E}((X-X_n)^2) = 2 \quad \forall \ n$. Is there an example of a sequence $X_n$ that does not depend on $X$ for its value, that still converges $L^2$ to $X$? Thanks